# Google Apps Script automatic (on edit) sort specific column (specific sheets only)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am hoping that someone might be able to help me out, I've been doing a lot of searching in the past few days and coming up short of a solution. Likely has to do with my lack of knowledge on coding... I know enough to be dangerous, just not enough to be effective or efficient. Previously, I had Google Sheet data who consist of several sheet. Let's it named sheet 1 and sheet 2. For sheet 2, there are many columns (column 1 until 7) where at the column 1 and column 5, containing partially blank row.

To start, here is my goal.

- To sort ascending my data from sheet 2 based column 3 and this sort only for sheet 2. Column 3 containing data date time.
- If there is any edit or update data, always sort automatically

i had create this script before, but it is not worked. There is problem "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheetByName')"

```
 function AutoSortOnEdit() {
 var sheetNames = ["Sheet 2"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getsheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet2") {
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({ column: 3, ascending: true });
  }
}
```